# Beta tester for android applictaion doesn't get updated version

Tags: android, versioning, alpha, google-play, beta

I defined alpha & beta testers group for application I develop. I added a specific user to both groups, and he used to get updates for both of them. I now removed this user from alpha group and noticed that he doesn't get anymore updates for beta version, while other users on this group keep getting the updates. I assume this is related to the fact I removed him from alpha group, I don't see any other reason why he stopped getting new beta versions after I removed him from this alpha group. I waited for more than 24 hours, usually he got updates after few hours.

Did anyone encountered this problem ? Any idea how it can be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by defining a new google group for beta testers, adding the relevant user to this group, and assigning this group to beta version instead of previous group.